# Why does XP randomly reset itself to the US keyboard layout?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout

I sometimes find that `"` and `@` have swapped places. There's no pattern to it that I can discern. It can happen in the middle of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you've inadvertently been hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>? That's the Windows shortcut for switching input languages. If so, you could uninstall the US English keyboard layout, like so:

1. Go to Control Panel / Regional and Language Settings / Language Settings / Details.
2. Under "installed services", mark "English US" and hit the "Remove" button next to the list.

Comment: Thanks. I now have only `English (Ireland)`.

Comment: Visual Studio users can suffer from this problem because SHIFT-ALT-ENTER is the shortcut to full screen mode.